# Metropolis Hastings algorithm and Markov chains

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

Why does Metropolis Hastings algorithm need/make a sequence of interdependent samples, i.e., a Markov chain in order to generate a posterior distribution?